# Cannot remove trailing characters

Tags: mysql, trim, trailing

I have a MySQL query that is showing no results for 95% of the time. The query is very simple and is supposed to get the days of week that backups need to be takes for a specific node. I imported the data from a CSV into mysql

I have found that when i edit a node name manually, delete the last character and retype it manually this fixes the problem for that node. So i susptected invisible trailing characters. i have tried to fix that with the following commands but it does nox fix the issue:

```
UPDATE tsm_nodes SET node_name = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM node_name);

UPDATE tsm_nodes SET node_name = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM node_name);

UPDATE tsm_nodes SET node_name = TRIM(node_name);
```

The solution from [THIS][1] SO question to show trailing chars shows 0 results:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(field) != CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(field))
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ts.daysofweek FROM tsm_schedules ts, tsm_nodes tn 
WHERE tn.node_name = ? AND tn.schedule = ts.name;
```

Is there another way to find out what trailing characters there are, they are in any care invisible. It is not an option to manually edit all fields as there are 1500+ nodes. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT2: To make things stranger, when i edit a node WITHOUT adjustind any information at all through PHPMyAdmin and save it again, the query works for that node.

EDIT:

In reply to suggestion by Jens: This does not show anything usefull:

```
+--------------------------------+
|         HEX(node_name)         |
+--------------------------------+
| 424F4E4866733031               |
| 424F4E486C696E3031             |
| 73716C32303035                 |
| 57324B382D6170706C31           |
| 57326B382D737978               |
| 4172636F323030382D3332626974   |
| 70726E736572766572             |
| 5365727665724172636F           |
| 77326B382D67656F6974           |
| 77326B382D736563757265         |
| 57324B382D65786368616E6765     |
| 57326B382D7368617265706F696E74 |
| 41444D2D41444D494E             |
| 42524F434144455242             |
| 41434E5F53514C5F44423032       |
| 41434E5F53514C5F4442           |
| 41434E5F53514C5F44423031       |
| 4745414343415448454E41         |
| 47454143434242433031           |
| 47454143434242433033           |
| 47454143434242433034           |
| 47454143434242433035           |
| 474541434345525041             |
| 474541434345525043             |
| 474541434345525045             |
+--------------------------------+
```

Allso the query from Rahul Tripathi does not fix is either:

```
UPDATE tsm_nodes SET node_name = TRIM(BOTH UNHEX('C2A0') FROM node_name)
```

Comment: You can use the `hex` funtion to sinf out what trailing char you have

Comment: You can try this: `TRIM(BOTH UNHEX('C2A0') FROM node_name)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this:

```
TRIM(BOTH UNHEX('C2A0') FROM node_name)
```

Comment: this has no effect. Thx for trying to help out though

Comment: @MartinLaw:- Try this: `TRIM(REPLACE(node_name,'\r\n',' '))` or may be `REPLACE(REPLACE(node_name, '\r', ''), '\n', '');`

Comment: Sadly no effect for both suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause. When i started to manually edit the entry's in PHPMyAdmin i noticed in the output from the query that the problem with the trailing characters was at the schedule field, not node_name

```
UPDATE `cipal`.`tsm_nodes` SET `schedule` = 'WE0230' WHERE `tsm_nodes`.`id` = 153;
```

after executing the following query the issue was resolved.

```
UPDATE tsm_nodes SET `schedule` = TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM `schedule`);
```